# Posting a message to slack via JS and API

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, slack-api, form-data

I'm trying to post a simple message to slack from a browser. I was able to upload a full file using the method I figured out here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600450/2278676

but when I transform that for the `chat.postMessage` API like below, nothing posts. I know it must be some simple thing I'm missing since I can upload a file, just not post text!

```
var mData = new FormData();
mData.append('token', 'my_token');
mData.append('channels', 'my_channel');
mData.append('text', 'test message');
mData.append('as_user', 'true');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST','https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage', true);

// Set up a handler for when the request finishes.
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // File(s) uploaded.
      console.log("posted");
  } else {
    alert('An error occurred!');
  }
};
xhr.send(mData);
```

I get the "posted" console log, and a status code: 200 in the network tab, but the chat isn't appearing in the channel. I've tried with and without the "as_user" line. Any thoughts?

Comment: Open console and read the response.

Comment: I'm getting a response 200

Comment: No, that's the status code.

Comment: ahhhhh I see. It says ok: false, and error:"channel_not_found" which is odd because it's the same channel I'm uploading the picture to.

Comment: no channel value seems to be accepted (I've tried passing the ID as well as the name value)

Comment: @singmotor I had tried your code for posting message But I had gone through this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913925/not-able-to-post-message-to-slack-with-slack-api-and-javascript 
could you help me if you dont mind?

Answer (score 1):

I was using "channels" as a key instead of "channel". that was the issue